# Access atributte processing algorithm

Tags: qgis, python

I have a doubt. In my plugin I use algorithms from processing sextante. For example:

```
Processing.runAlgorithm("grass:v.to.rast.attribute", None, inputLayer, 0, Indexes, extent, cellSize, -1.0, 0.0001, outPath)
```

inputlayer = directory of inputlayer
extent = defined extent of the new raster file
cellsize = option for user to choose the cellsize
outPath = output raster directory
and other parameters that doesn't matter here

but my question is in the attribute field (that is defined as Indexes in the example). This parameter is the attribute field to rasterize. So, usually, I used a combobox to define this parameter but in this case I create, internally, a new column with values and I want to use this column. But I don't know how this parameter are defined, as a list, as a stringm...? Does anyone know that? Or how I can access the attribute created by me?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I found the answer to my question.
The attribute field is given by the name of the attribute, so is only necessary to read the attributes of the layer (including the new attribute) and then pick the attribute needed.

Thanks anyway!